# Using more than one Google Analytics property ID in Smartface apps

Tags: google-analytics, smartface.io

Is is possible to implement more than one Google Analytics property (ID) in Smartface apps? If possible, how can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

only one google-analytics instance works in an application.

You can read more about http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/plugins/google-analytics/

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to use multiple properties with HTTP calls.

With Measurement Protocol, it's possible to send data to Google Analytics.
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/

It requires a bit manual effort, but you can use it in any kind of environment.